# How do programming language translators work?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm a programmer and I'm looking to play around with translating one language to another. Say C# to Lua. I'm curious as to how translating languages like that works? I would think there is some kind of standard methodology that I could perhaps look into for this or is it pretty raw?

Comment: That's what most compilers do. Translate from one language to another (normally lower level one). Any book about compilers will give you an introduction to all the concepts you need in order to achieve this.

Comment: There is a significant difference between translations that preserves semantics (i.e. results of the program), and translations that turn one human-readable program into another human-readable program. The latter is much harder and much less useful, which kind are you talking about?

Comment: This one: "human-readable program into another human-readable program"

Comment: Then be warned that Oded's comment, and most compiler resources, doesn't fully apply. Most compilers are of the other kind, they have a rather different focus (e.g. the vast literature on optimization is of no use for a translator that outputs human-readable code, and most material on code generation assumes machine code or some assembly-like low-level language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parser can take source code from a language and turn it into a [sort of tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Since any language can be represented this way, translating is a matter of turning the source code from one language into a syntax tree and then reversing the process to turn that tree into the source code of the target language.

There are, of course, finer details - the languages must have corresponding features, so there may be programs in language A that can't be expressed directly in language B; you'd have to stick to the subset of features that's common to both. The same could be said of the standard libraries - you could translates a `printf` in C to a `System.out.printf` in Java but there are things that have no obvious translation.

Further reading: [The nature of Lisp](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp.html)

Comment: I'll dig my heals into a syntax tree. Never heard of that before. Thanks!

The turning to xml is a great idea!